# Using vector<String> with JTable

Tags: java, swing, vector, jtable

I have a vector of String type entries formed as:

```
Vector<String> nameLst = new Vector<String>();
nameLst.add("Jacob");
nameLst.add("Stacey");
```

[...etc]

I to not know the number of entries - hence the vector instead of array. I would like to be able to display those names in a tale (with possibility of editing). My problem is, that JTable uses only Vector but my implementation only uses a list (rather then a table)
I was trying to go through all the entries of nameLst and allocate then in a new vector:

```
Vector<Vector<String>> helper = new Vector<Vector<String>>
for (String nametmp : nameLst){
Vector<String> a = new Vector<String>();
a.add(nametmp);
helper.add((Vector<String>)a.clone())
}
```

However the table (while formated correct) remains empty. I would expect that the data should stay safe and not go out of scope since I'm cloning it into the helper vector. 
Is there a way to get a Vector to populate a JTable?

EDIT: Example - I don't really have a minimum *working* example, but the relevant code is:

1. The Display (in the Gui class):

   ```
   JPanel namPan;
   JTable namTab
   ```
2. In the constructor:

   ```
   namePan = new JPanel();
   ```
3. printNames() //method

   ```
   public void printNames(){
   Vector<String> label= new Vector<String>();
   Vector<Vector<String>> helper = new Vector<Vector<String>>;
   for(String nametmp :nameLst){
   Vector<String> a = new Vector<String>();
   a.add(nametmp);
   helper.add((Vector<String>/*just a cast*/) a.clone());
   }
   label.add("Currently active:");
   namTab = new JTable(helper, label);
   namPan.add(new JScrollPane(namTab));
   }
   ```

Afterwards I call the Gui Constructor, fill in the name list with some initial names and call the printNames() method.

I think the core problem is the mismatch of formats - The Vector looks like ['a' 'b' 'c'] wile it should be a column vector: [a] [b] [c]. or in other words be seen as 2d vector with one column and multiple rows.

EDIT2

Found it - Special thanks to Hovercraft Full Of Eels who pushed me to make a minimal working example. I could not find any critical differences between what He uploaded and what I made, however when I've made the minimum example - stripped all other gui elements and functionalities I saw the data!
**What happened?** I put some dimension restrictions on the window size and panel ratios (GridBagLayout) and the test strings were outside! When entire area was available to the table I could see the text. I decided to write that and look like a fool rather then shove it under the carpet and leave this post hanging.

Comment: In general, it is agreed here that [you shouldn't use greetings or salutations in your posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276033/pointless-question-edit/276037#276037). They get in the way of us readers figuring out the actual question. I've edited them out for you this time.

Comment: For better help, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't want to see your whole program, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: You see your question is really why this: `"However the table (while formated correct) remains empty."` is happening, and the reason is likely due to code you've not shown, hence my recommendation in my comment above.

Comment: `"I don't really have a minimum working example."` -- then consider making one since that's what most of us would have to do to fully understand your problem and help you, but since it's your question, the onus of effort should be yours.

Comment: And in fact, I've made an MCVE and have demonstrated that your code **does** work and that the problem lies elsewhere, proving that your assumptions about the location of your error and thus your question is currently invalid. I posit that without an MCVE, you will not get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: You can find it [here](http://pastebin.com/f61McKCP). And you can use this to start creating your MCVE if desired.

Comment: From What I see you generate the table first, but I can't do the same (I've tried printing the content of the helper in a console and it does produce string output.
I am working on isolating the relevant parts of code, but I've put myself into kind of spaghetti code situation.

Comment: @user3002166: isolate your problem is a requirement to solve it. We can discuss this back and forth for hours if you wish, but again, I think that you will not get a decent solution until you first do the required work of isolation. I'm out of here until you comment back that you've created and posted your mcve.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable lesson - I've found the problem and added explanation to the initial post. Thanks again - if you didn't push the MCVE subject I'd probably never find it.

Comment: Thanks for the update on the problem and its resolution and congratulations on solving it. The lesson here I suppose is you've learned a new debugging tool.